# Function with exclusion of one parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a delete function that takes an ID parameter, and I need it to work every time except when id === 1. How can this be done?

```
  const handleDeleteEmail = (emailId: number) => {
    dispatch(deleteEmailTemplate(emailId));
    EmailTemplatesApi.deleteEmailTemplate(emailId);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the condition is met using an `if` statement as follow:

```
const handleDeleteEmail = (emailId: number) => {
  if(emailId !== 1) {
    dispatch(deleteEmailTemplate(emailId));
    EmailTemplatesApi.deleteEmailTemplate(emailId);
  }
};
```